# How to get the first div contains a text inside html/text?

Tags: java, jsoup

i am using JSOUP
and I have html/text something like:

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">
</style></head>
<body><div style="font-family:times new roman,new york,times,serif;font-size:14pt">first text<br><div><br></div><div style="font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 14pt;"><br><div style="font-family: times new roman,new york,times,serif; font-size: 12pt;"><font size="2" face="Tahoma"><hr size="1"><b><span style="font-weight: bold;">one:</span></b> second text<br><b><span style="font-weight: bold;">two:</span></b> third text<br><b><span style="font-weight: bold;">three:</span></b> fourth text<br><b><span style="font-weight: bold;">five:</span></b> fifth text<br></font><br>
```

and I want to extract the first div that contains a text (the whole div)
to get an output like:

```
<div style="font-family:times new roman,new york,times,serif;font-size:14pt">first text<br></div>
```

and one more question is how to get the first html tag (in general) that contains a text meaning the first text maybe inside `<p>` or `<span>`

thanks in advance

Comment: Very similar to your last question, but just a bit different.

Comment: i thought that it's better to ask this question in a new post rather than asking in the old one, since i see it's bit different as you mentioned.

Comment: off-topic, your website url http://www.edwinbuck.com/ forwards me to the apache home page :) :)

Comment: off-topic, my url is used for items other than a vanity web site :)  It's not forwarding you to anywhere, it's displaying the default "index.html" web page for a newly installed apache web server.

Comment: That div is not a full div. The 2nd div element does not close the 1st div, it just starts another div element. If you're talking about `<div>....</div>` then it's easy with Jsoup.

Comment: @BalusC any hints on how to do that ?

Comment: Your HTML example is still bad. This is too much a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SAX styled HTML parser, like [TagSoup](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers/tagsoup).

To do this, initialize the parser with an extended `DefaultHandler` to cache the last element visited in a local member variable, then detect when the first time the `characters(...)` method is called and print out the cached element and the text result.

Look to http://sax.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html for some direction in how to setup the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML parser, or, if you know that HTML is XHTML, XSLT processor

[Here is the list](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) of open-source HTML parsers.

Comment: i am using jsoup, but i don't know how to do that with it

Comment: @sword101. Why did not you put this piece of data into the question? Don't you think it's important?

Comment: forgive me, i thought that the tag would be enough, really sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score -1):

What about loading a temporaty DOM (a DOMFragment http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) then turn to jQuery to find the div you want inside the fragment?